# How does Go open files?

Tags: go

I built a Go Web Project with Iris version 12, and now there is a file named `config.go`, I can output `config.json` by shell script `cat ../config.json` in the folder which includes `config.go`, but Go note me that `panic: open ../config.json: no such file or directory`.
The structure of the folder is as following:

```
.
├── config
│   └── config.go
├── config.json
├── config.yml
├── controller
├── datasource
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
├── model
│   └── user.go
├── service
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── app.85873a69abe58e3fc37a13d571ef59e2.css
│   ├── favicons
│   │   └── favicon.ico
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── element-icons.b02bdc1.ttf
│   ├── img
│   │   └── default.jpg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       ├── 0.6e924665f4f8679a8f0b.js
└── util
```

**P.S.** I also tried `./../config.json` which is **available** in shell and **not available** in Go.

The `config.go` was as following:

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type AppConfig struct {
    AppName    string `json:"app_name"`    // Project name
    Port       int    `json:"port"`        // Server port
    StaticPath string `json:"static_path"` // The path of static resources
    Mode       string `json:"mode"`        // Development mode
}

func InitConfig() *AppConfig {
    file, err := os.Open("../config.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    conf := AppConfig{}
    err = decoder.Decode(&conf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return &conf
}
```

Comment: The location of your source files has no bearing on the relative location of any other files at runtime.

Comment: Unrelated: Do not use Iris.

Comment: Dear Flimzy: So how to solve this problem? Use the absolute path to solve this?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. A common one is to store your config files in `~/.app-config.yaml` for example.

Comment: Think about how other programs handle configuration: they usually expect either a fixed absolute path (like `/etc/myapp.conf`) or take a config path by command line (like `myapp -config ./myapp.conf`).

Answer (score 7):

Relative path is always relative to the current working directory of the running process (which necessarily doesn't have to be a directory where the executable is). It has nothing to do with where original source file is.

To debug your issue you can try print out the current working directory just before you try to read the config file:

```golang
cwd, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(cwd)
```

Relative path given to `os.Open()` is then added to that path.

If you run your program from the root of repository then the proper path to config will be simply `os.Open("config.json")` (unless you change working directory somewhere in code by calling `os.Chdir()`).

Answer (score -1):

Just delete `../` from file path. If You have file in root of project dir - just use filename to access it from every place in project.

```
func InitConfig() *AppConfig {
    file, err := os.Open("config.json")
}
```

project structure:

[image]

result:

[image]

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "scripts/playground/config"
)

func main() {
    cfg := config.InitConfig()
    fmt.Printf("%+v", cfg)
}
```